# reverse-engineering JS listening to device orientation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to determine how a mobile device, that's visiting my website, rotates in physical space, using JS. This seemed like a really easy thing at first but I already spent several hours trying to get this to work, and I can't…

This is a really cool demo that I found: https://sensor-js.xyz/demo.html – I just need the Beta(β) and Gamma(γ) values and I don't want a start / stop button. – I looked at the source-code of the demo and tried to reverse-engineer it, but I was not successful.

This was my code:

```js
function handleOrientation(event) {
    var absolute = event.absolute;
    var alpha    = event.alpha;
    var beta     = event.beta;
    var gamma    = event.gamma;
    
    document.querySelector(".deviceAbsolute").innerHTML = absolute;
    document.querySelector(".deviceAlpha").innerHTML = alpha;
    document.querySelector(".deviceBeta").innerHTML = beta;
    document.querySelector(".deviceGamma").innerHTML = gamma;
}

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Build 7</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
    deviceAbsolute = <span class="deviceAbsolute">no input</span><br>
    deviceAlpha = <span class="deviceAlpha">no input</span><br>
    deviceBeta = <span class="deviceBeta">no input</span><br>
    deviceGamma = <span class="deviceGamma">no input</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is some of the documentation that I looked at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation // https://sensor-js.xyz/webs-sixth-sense-ccs18.pdf

---

*I would very much appreciate any sort of help, Thank You! – Simon*

Comment: @Teemu Thank You, for your answer, but I'm not just trying to determine landscape / portrait. – I need precise Beta and Gamma values, measured in degrees.

Comment: Code works fine for me: https://kq1qv.csb.app/ (mobile Chrome) Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-glitter-kq1qv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @ChrisG Do you mean it does not just say: `no input` – Do you actually get values?

Comment: Because I did a lot of testing and it never worked…

Comment: Here's a screenshot from my phone: https://i.imgur.com/UvcvmZ7.png (some phones don't have orientation sensors; I assume your phone does? which browser app are you using?)

Comment: @ChrisG Man that is so weird… I tried this with my iPad / iPhone, using Safari, Opera-Touch and Chrome. …and I know it's possible to do this on iOS. – Are you getting some sort of Pop-Up, when visiting the site, asking for consent?

Comment: No, nothing, it just works. When you visit the site you linked, it works for you, right?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes the demo from sensor-js works but I just can not get my own code to run on my devices, I've been working on this for two days now, this is so weird… The codesandbox also doesn't work.

Comment: This works without any problems: https://sensor-js.xyz/demo.html But this is the only demo that I found that worked on my iPhone / iPad…

Comment: Maybe it only works once you interacted with the page? No idea, I don't use iOS devices.